# How to prevent automatic url- rewiting in Magento 1.9.0.1?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I am having problem while `url-rewriting`, I am creating custom `url-rewrite` in which Requested path is

```
products/kitchen-cleaner/screen-wipes
```

Target path is

```
screen-wipes
```

but it automatically generate and redirecting on `screen-wipes-21`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try clearing cache and index management?

Every time you add a catalog url rewrite it is good to clear your Magento cache.

Also I am not sure if both URL exist. In case of redirection target url must be present in your system.

URL

```
products/kitchen-cleaner/screen-wipes
```

is a category product list url and you wanna show it like

```
screen-wipes
```

For that make sure if screen-wipes is accessible directly. Otherwise .htaccess may help you. Magento Catalog URL Rewrite would not be a good idea in this case.

Comment: Try to find screen-wipes-21 in Target Path under Catalog URL Rewrite. Possible if already it is linked.

Comment: Accept answer if your issue is solved.